# VS code Extension : How to add an authentication to plugin

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to develop an extension for VS code.
It gonna save and store the highlighted commands to the extension state store.
This part is ready :)

What I want to do now is try to understand whether I can store these commands  on top of VS code state in my existing backend
So, I need to somehow build some authentication logic

Is there a way to build the authentication process into an extension?

Comment: where is your `backend`? VSC is an editor and has nothing to with your runtime. What are `highlighted commands`?

Comment: 1) Backend is outside of VS code. It is my API hosted in AWS
2) In VS code extension it is possible to have JS code. So, I wanna know if it supports some authentication outside or inside the vs code. Maybe something like auth redirection outside vs code and returning auth token back to extension

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my scenario used in the extension `Docs-validation`:
We provide a sign-in button inside the VS CODE, when the user clicks that button, we will redirect the user to a browser to do the auth, after that, an auth token will be sent back to the extension, which will be used to call our backend API.
The main logic can be found in this [file](https://github.com/docascode/vscode-docs-build/blob/master/src/credential/credentialController.ts)

Actually, this is inspired by the built-in sign-in experience of the VS Code and some extension with a sign-in experience like `azure-cli`, you can see from here:
[image]

Comment: Man, this is exactly what I've been looking for :) 
thank you!

Comment: Hey, is line 177 the part of the code that I should be looking at?

Comment: The link no longer works :(